# Magento 2.2 customer custom attribute not saving in adminend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

This is code I have used to add the attribute to customer via installData

```
*/
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

    /*$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = 1; 
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'customer_mobile'); */

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup->startSetup();

    $attributesInfo = [
            'customer_mobile' => [
                'label' => 'Mobile',
                'type' => 'static',
                'input' => 'text',
                'position' => 140,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true 
        ] 
    ];

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        }

    $vatIdAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'customer_mobile');
        $vatIdAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']
        );

    $vatIdAttribute->save();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to save Customer Attribute

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test Field',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true, 
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'system' => 0,

        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to run

```
setup:upgrade
cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank You,
I have tried now but my custom field is not displaying in adminend customer info form.

Comment: is it working ??

Comment: custom field is not displaying. Then I changed "eav_attribute" table field "is_user_defined" value  1 to 0  then custom field is displaying in admin form

Comment: can not save data into database..