# Unable to create customer custom attribute

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.2, custom-attributes, magento-2.2.1

I need to add a custom attribute to customers. 
For products I did it with REST API, but it seems it is not possible to do the same for customers.

So, as suggested everywhere, I created a small extension to add the desired attributes, with a setup module, that implements the install method, like this

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Handouk_CustomerAttributes" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>           
                <module name="Magento_Customer"/>  
            </sequence>   
        </module>
    </config>
```

Handouk/CustomerAttributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Handouk\CustomerAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_attr' , [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'my_attr' ,
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true, 
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'system' => 0,

            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, )
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);            
            $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Anyway, to me, this is not working and attributes are not visible in backend. 
I read people were telling that for Magento 2.1 this approach was not working either.

My question is: is it the correct approach, given that I'm on Magento 2.2.1?

Comment: check my answer -
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212296/magento-2-2-customer-custom-attribute-not-saving-in-adminend/212299

Comment: yea @AbhishekPanchal that is the approach I am following. I want to know if it is supposed to work also in M2.2.1 as to me it does not work.

Comment: did you get any error when you try to run `setup:upgrade` command?

Comment: No any error. The module is correctly added and results as enabled. I also tried regenerating static-content after cleaning cache.... but no traces of my attributes. Not even in eav_attribute table

Comment: is your script working for 1 attribute only.. Try adding 1 attribute instead foreach loop

Comment: I've also tried that approach, but no luck. How could I check the module is recompiled every time I run the setup:upgrade is run?  because i've even tried to put an error in the module and no exception is raised, as it is not considered at all....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73257/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-sissy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to save Customer Attribute

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test Field',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true, 
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'system' => 0,

        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to run

```
setup:upgrade
cache:flush
```